# Calling methods on string literals (Java)

Tags: java, string, object

I know that string literals are objects. 
According to

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Classes,_Objects_and_Types

> When an object is created, a reference to the object is also created. **The object can not be accessed directly in Java, only through this object reference.** This object reference has a type assigned to it. We need this type when passing the object reference to a method as a parameter.

But are we violating this when we have literals access String methods?

For example:

```
System.out.println("Literal".toUpperCase());
```

Isn't this directly accessing the object? as opposed to accessing the object through the reference.

For example:

```
String x = "Literal"; 
System.out.println(x.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: You can see `"Literal"` just like `new String("Literal")`. `String` is not really a magic class, it is just creating instance using a specific system

Comment: It works pretty similar to when you call something on the return value of a method `someMethod().doSomething()`. You do not have a dedicated *name* (I mean variable) to point to the instance, but you still have a *reference* to the instance, returned by the method.

Comment: I find "The object can not be accessed directly in Java, only through this object reference." a non-sensical and confusing remark (your question clearly shows how the remark is confusing) The object reference is what identifies the object instance. You cannot access something if you can't identify it. There is no more "direct" method than this.

Comment: Just a minor note: Strings created using literals come out of the internal String Cache (String interning). As opposed to `new String(...)` which would always create a fresh new uncached value.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I guess it refers to the memory backing the object, you cannot access that as a value. But you're right, using the term "object" for that is misleading.

Comment: @Bergi there is no more direct way to access memory than through something that points to an offset in memory. There is no instruction for the CPU that doesn't include a pointer to the memory. The JVM doesn't specify if an object reference is a pointer or something else (indirection for example) but it often is a pointer. (It goes too far to explain when it is and isn't)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sure you always need an offset, what I meant specifically was accessing the memory as raw bytes. You can't clone an object by simply copying them to elsewhere in memory (like you could in C), the data is always hidden behind the object abstraction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Isn't this directly accessing the object? as opposed to accessing the object through the reference.

No, you're still using a reference. The value of an expression which is a string literal is a string reference. It's still not an object that you access directly.

In your example, the value of `x` is still a reference, and your two snippets are equivalent except for the presence of the variable `x`.

Comment: so a string literal is a reference to a string object that holds data that is the string literal?

Comment: @omaewa: Well I'd say "that holds the same sequence of characters as is present in the string literal". It's not like there's an extra level of indirection involved - it's just a reference to a string with the right content.

Comment: interesting! and this would be a special feature of strings in java right?

Comment: Not so special. There are also class literals, and the null literal is also a literal that evaluates to an object reference.

Comment: @omaewa A reference is not something that is necessarily visible in source code